# python connector to neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'cypher'

This is what I get when I run the sample from the neo4j doc website

details

```
c:\Python\Scripts>mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t neo4j:db@localhost:7474/
db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
Logging to mongo-connector.log.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\util.py", line 85, in wrappe
d
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py", line 261,
 in run
    docman.upsert(doc, ns, timestamp)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\neo4j_doc_manag
er.py", line 60, in upsert
    self.apply_id_constraint(builder.doc_types)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\neo4j_doc_manag
er.py", line 47, in apply_id_constraint
    self.graph.cypher.execute(constraint)
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'cypher'
```

Comment: which version of `py2neo` you are using ?
`pip search py2neo`

Comment: You are probably using version 3, downgrade to version 2.0.9 for now

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.run` instead of `.cypher` in your code.